# MySQL: How do I search and replace chars at the beginning of a string

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to search and replace mobile numbers with the full international code.
So where rows have 07970000007 to replace the beginning with +447970000007

```
UPDATE tblMemberImportClub 
SET msisdn = REPLACE(msisdn, '07', '+447') 
WHERE INSTR(msisdn, '07') = 1;
```

But this also replaces the other matches:

+4479700000+447

I don't think i can use TRIM as some rows will already start with +447 and will therefore nor require any updates.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE` and `INSERT()`:

```
UPDATE tblMemberImportClub 
    SET msisdn = INSERT(msisdn, 1, 2, '+447') 
    WHERE msisdn LIKE '07%';
```

`INSERT()` is a string function that replaces exactly the characters you specify (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)).

Comment: Thanks, It helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  

CONCAT(
                   REPLACE(
                             LEFT('07970000007',2), '07', '+447'
                   ),      
                   SUBSTRING('07970000007', 3, CHAR_LENGTH('07970000007'))
       )as replaced
```